# Adding GIF to frame

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to add a GIF to the frame. Here is my code but when I run it  cannot see GIF. Is there a function to add GIF to java?
Any help would be appreciated.

```java
public class confetti extends JFrame
{
    private static JFrame frame;

    public confetti() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(510, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        addConfetti();
    }

    public static void addConfetti() {
        JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel();
        JLabel lblgif = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("confetti-40.gif"));
        frame.add(jpCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lblgif.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new confetti();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `lblgif` to `jpCenter` ... and Swing components (with the exception of windows) are visible by default

Comment: thankss it is working right now.

Answer (score 2):

You never add your label to any frame/panel. In your code it might be something like this:

```
    public static void addConfetti() {
        JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel();
        JLabel lblgif = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("path/to/your/confetti-40.gif"));
        frame.add(jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jpCenter.add(lblgif);
        lblgif.setVisible(true);
        
      }
```

Also check your absolute path from your projecto to your gif file, your code in works for me on my PC.

Comment: Don’t use file paths, use embedded resources, saves on fixing issues when run on different systems